# Change the date format in grid.column using ASP.NET a SQL Server designed in Webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webmatrix, date-format

I’m really stuck in trying to get a short date format in a table using Webmatrix. Although my column `StartDate` is defined in the SQL Server database as a date (not date/time), Windows Azure somehow converts it into a Date/Time field. Doesn’t bother me except that I now want to remove all the midnight times to simply show a `dd/mm/yy` date format.

I’ve obviously not tried all combinations or am missing something in the coding, but the `grid.Column` line just refuses to compile once I add a format option.

```
   @grid.GetHtml( 
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("StartDate", header:"StartDate")
        )
    )
```

Based on similar questions asked on this forum, I’ve tried all of these:

```
    grid.Column("StartDate", header:"StartDate", format:@<text>@item.StartDate.ToString("dd/mm/yy")</text>))
    grid.Column("StartDate", header:"StartDate", format:@@<text>@item.StartDate.ToString("dd/mm/yy")</text>))
    grid.Column("StartDate", header:"StartDate", format: "{0:d}")
    grid.Column("StartDate", header:"StartDate", format: "{0:dd/mm/yy}")
```

Would appreciate if anyone could point out where I’m going wrong.  I’m only a newbie so I hope it's something silly.

Thanks,

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

`mm` is for minutes. Change to `MM`.

```
grid.Column("StartDate", header:"StartDate", format: "{0:dd/MM/yy}")
```

Comment: Thanks AVD,
Unfortunately it still doesn't work with this code.  I still get this error:
Regards,
Dave.

Answer (score 0):

This WebGrid column format works for me:

```
grid.Column("StartDate", header:"StartDate", format: @<text>@item.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")</text>))
```

Simply replace mm with MM (as suggested by AVD) in your first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.  This works for me:

```
grid.Column("StartDate", "StartDate", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yy}", item.StartDate))
```